# Save symbols in database

Tags: php, database

How can I save this for example:
✰ Back 2 School ✰
In my database, without the star symbol doesn't "break" when I want to echo it out again?
I've tried with htmlspecialchars and htmlentities, but without luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

which database? any system with utf-8 encoding will be ok, probably you use MySQL without setting proper client and target column encoding. When your encoding is correct on both client and db side you won't have to encode data with any additional function calls.

Comment: My collation is: latin1_swedish_ci
Can that be the reason?